# Preload several MPMoviePlayerController instances

Tags: ios, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

I would like to be able to preload several videos in a UICollectionView.

I am not interested in playing back several of them at the same time, I just would like to be able to get the controls on the screen. Unfortunately, if I call `[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay]` on all of them, I only get the last one "prepared" to be played back.

My ultimate goal would be to be able to show all the controls behind each instance of MPMoviePlayerController and, whenever the user taps on each play button, the video starts (and the other playing, if any, gets stopped).

Another attempt I made was to use `moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded`, but the controls are not shown until the video "gets prepared" as aforementioned.

Any clue?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just add a custom play button over the movie thumbnail?

Comment: Well, that's a solution.. but I would prefer the movie controls, if possible. That's still a work-around that I was already considering.